# org.springframework.beans.NotReadablePropertyException:Invalid property

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

Invalid property 'stCode' of bean class [java.lang.String]: Bean property 'stCode' is not readable or has an invalid getter method: Does the return type of the getter match the parameter type of the setter?

```
Regist.jsp
```

```
<div class="container">
        <div class="row centered-form">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-8 col-md-4 col-sm-offset-2 col-md-offset-4">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                        </div>
                        <div class="panel-body">
                        <f:form action="registSave" modelAttribute="r" method="post">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        State Name
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <f:input path="stCode" class="form-control input-sm"/>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        District Name
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <f:input path="distCode" class="form-control input-sm"/>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        Phone number
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <f:input path="phone" class="form-control input-sm"/>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        Name
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <f:input path="name" class="form-control input-sm"/>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <!-- <div class="form-group">
                                <input type="email" name="email" id="email" class="form-control input-sm" placeholder="Email Address">
                            </div>

                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <input type="password" name="password" id="password" class="form-control input-sm" placeholder="Password">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <input type="password" name="password_confirmation" id="password_confirmation" class="form-control input-sm" placeholder="Confirm Password">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div> -->
                            
                            <input type="submit" value="Register" class="btn btn-info btn-block">
                        
                        </f:form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

```
RBean
```

```
package max.Bean;


public class RBean {
    
    String stCode;
    String distCode;
    String phone;
    String name;
    public String getStCode() {
        return stCode;
    }
    public void setStCode(String stCode) {
        this.stCode = stCode;
    }
    public String getDistCode() {
        return distCode;
    }
    public void setDistCode(String distCode) {
        this.distCode = distCode;
    }
    public String getPhone() {
        return phone;
    }
    public void setPhone(String phone) {
        this.phone = phone;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    

}
```

```
Controller
```

```
package max;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

import max.Bean.RBean;

@Controller
public class MainController {
    
    @Autowired
    RBean rBean;
    
    @RequestMapping("home")
    public String home()
    {
        return "registLayout";
    }
    
    @RequestMapping("regist")
    public ModelAndView registration()
    {
        return new ModelAndView("reg","r","rBean");
    }
    
    @RequestMapping(value="registSave", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView registrationSave(@ModelAttribute("r") RBean rBean)
    {
        return new ModelAndView("reg","r","rBean");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are trying to set `rBean` into `r` variable which is available in view then you should remove the `"` used for `rBean`. Eg: `return new ModelAndView("reg","r",rBean);`

Comment: It was very silly mistake though. How couldn't I see this..lol. Anyways thank you so much.